# Incompatible operand type between variable and string

Tags: java

I'm facing an error of incompiatble operand type between one my variable and string. Here's a snippet of my code. The error happens @ if ( handler == "CLOSE" )

On top of that, did I connet my db correctly? There should be a 'public void closeDB but there's error when include the statement.

```
private DBHandler handler;
public void openDB() throws SQLException
    {
        // Open the DB Connection
        final String DBURL = "example";
        final String DBUSER = "example";
        final String DBPASS = "example";

        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void setMySQL( String mySQL )
    {
        this.mySQL = mySQL;
    }

    public ResultSet retrieveTheData(  ) throws SQLException
    {
        if ( handler == null )
        {
            // Create a new connection
        }

        if ( handler == "CLOSE" )
        {
            // Open the connection
        }

        // Message the Data 


        ResultSet rs;
        return rs;
    }
```

Comment: the type of both variable is different

Comment: handler is not a string. It is a Object of type `DBHandler` so you can not compare it.

Comment: Probably should be `handler.getName ().equals ("CLOSE')` or something.

Answer (score 2):

Use String's [equals(Object anObject)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) for your job:

```
"CLOSE".equals(handler.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure with handler (character case)you can use equalsIgnoreCase() otherwise simply equals() method as

```
"CLOSE".equalsIgnoreCase(handler.toString());
```

or

```
"CLOSE".equals(handler.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
handler.toString().equals( "CLOSE" )
```

but the way @sumit Singh answered , using

```
"CLOSE'.equals(handler.toString())
```

rather than

```
handler.toString().equals( "CLOSE" ) )
```

you prevent null pointer exception.

if you want to handle that diffrently it's better to use my answer and catch it's null pointer exception